# Initialise global array with respect to function input

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to do something like:

```
int a[][];  // I know this code won't work, its to demonstrate what I want to do

void func(int n, int m){
    a = int[n][m];
}
```

that is, initialise a global array whose size depends on function input. If this array was local, it would be a trivial case, but I don't know how to do this in the case shown above. Any help would be very useful!

Comment: Make or get a matrix class that uses a 1d `std::vector` under the hood.  That gives you the best performance and ease of use.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica I got that, but is there any method that is strictly restricted to arrays?

Comment: Nope.  An array's size must be known at compile time.  If you only know the size at run time, you need dynamic allocation and you should use a `std::vector` to handle that for you.

Comment: You could make `a` a pointer into an array of pointers instead of an array of arrays. But initializing it and cleaning it up get a bit tricky, especially considering exception safety.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica got it. Thanks!

Comment: @aschepler yes, it is indeed tricky. Thanks for the suggestion! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a matrix with `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> a;

void func(int n, int m) {
    a.resize(n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a[i].resize(m);
    }
}
```

Then you can access elements in the same way you do with `int a[][]`:

```
a[i][j] = number;
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is to encapsulate a flat `std::vector` in a `Matrix` class and use math to get an element with row and column as in this example:

```
template<typename T>
class Matrix {
private:
    vector<T> vec;
//...
public:
    T& get_value(size_t const row, size_t const col) {
        return vec[row * col_count + col];
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
int ** a; // is a pointer of two dimension

void func(int n, int m){
    a = new int*[n]; //dynamic allocation global pointer a
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        a[i] = new int[m]();
}
```

Comment: Just no.  `new` has no place here.  It is dangerous and error prone and a lot worse than `std::vector<std::vector<int>> a; void func(int n, int m){ a = std::vector<std::vector<int>>(n, std::vector<int>(m)); }`

Comment: However your solution gets work but as @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica said, it's better to use vector class